# How would I repeatedly add a byte value to a byte array x amount of times based on the value in the index before it?

Tags: java, arrays, encoding, decoding

I am working on an RLE Encoding project in Java, and have 8 methods to complete. One of them involves taking a byte array that represents compressed RLE byte array (ex: {3, 15, 6, 4}) and decompress it to its original values ({15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}). How would I for-loop the solution to where it adds the second value in the compressed array x number of times (adding value of 15 three times to a new byte array for instance, or value of 4 six times to the new array).

I tried creating two for-loops that are nested, and I wonder if I could convert the byte value at every odd index to an int and have every even number in this case repeatedly append to the byte array that number of times based on the int of the odd index number before it. I don't know how would I have to implement that method though. I have already created a method that encodes an RLE byte array (compressing {15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} to where it returns {3, 15, 6, 4}). And essentially I have to do the reverse and bring it back to the former byte array.

The method to encode RLE data

```
        int countRunResult = countRuns(flatData);
        ByteArrayOutputStream returnedEncoded = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for(int i = 0; i < flatData.length; i++){
            int runLength = 1;
            while(i+1 < flatData.length && flatData[i] == flatData[i+1]){
                runLength++;
                i++;
            }
            returnedEncoded.write((byte)runLength);
            returnedEncoded.write((byte)flatData[i]);
        }
        return returnedEncoded.toByteArray();
    }
```

What I have so far for decoding the RLE data

```
        int initialLength = getDecodedLength(rleData);
        byte[] returnDecoded = new byte[initialLength];
           for(int i = 0; i < initialLength; i++){
                for(int j = 1; j < initialLength; j+=2){

                    returnDecoded[i] = rleData[j];
                }

            }

        return returnDecoded;   
    }
```

I expected {15, 15, 15, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4} in this example case but I received an error out of bounds message saying:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index > 5 out of bounds for length 4
>   at RleProgram.decodeRle(RleProgram.java:61)
>   at RleProgram.main(RleProgram.java:99)

Comment: Looks like `getDecodedLength` returns the encoded length, not the decoded length, hence your array has length 4 instead of 9.

Comment: @Jannik Thank you. It successfully returned a value, albeit for some reason when printing the byte array as a string as I'm testing it out, it returns something like "╝╝╝╝". Would you have any clue as to why? It's happened a few times when creating my other methods though I can't remember how exactly I resolved it. Thank you again.

Comment: It looks like an encoding problem. If you get the bytes of a string in one character encoding and then recreate the string with a different encoding the characters might change. On the other hand it might be possible that your encoding or decoding screws the data up. You could use a debugger to check that the RL encoded array is as expected and decoded array is the same as the input array.